# opening new tab on IE 11 (not new window) using selenium

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to open a new tab in IE 11 by clicking on a link but instead it opens a new window for when clicking on a link. I googled for proper way of doing it but cant figure out how to achive that. Can any one please help?

While clicking manually link opens in a tab but when doing in by selenium it opens a new window.

I am not adding any code as there is not much to add . I clicked link element using webElement.click() and i have disabled persistentHover in driver capability and I am using selenium with java.

Answer (score 0):

```
String openInNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN); 
webElement.sendKeys(openInNewTab);
```